# How to make 403 error is oaky for API testing in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter

I know In general JMeter automatically treats samplers with HTTP Status Code above 400 as failed , but I am doing the security testing for the API's such as 403 forbidden.

Snice I expect 403 forbidden error, how do I make Report is PASSED for 403 forbidden error.

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59485324/handle-negative-cases-in-jmeter-for-example-my-expected-output-response-is-400/59485393#59485393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for [HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) expected status code using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured as follows:

[image]

1. It will suppress JMeter's automatic marking HTTP Status Codes above 400 as failed
2. It will check whether response code is equal to 403 and fail the Sampler(s) in the Assertion's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) in the opposite case

More information: [What Are JMeter Response Assertions?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter)